# How do I only get the manufacturer who didn't ship in a certain month?

Tags: sql, where-clause

I have a postgres database with 3 tables (product, deliveries and manufactures).

```
create table manufacturer (
  hnr   varchar(4),
  name  varchar(30),
  city varchar(30),
  primary key (hnr)
);
create table product (
 pnr   varchar(4),
 name  varchar(30),
 hnr   varchar(4),
 price numeric(8,2),
 primary key (pnr)
);
create table delivery (
  lnr   varchar(6),
  pnr   varchar(4),
  datum date,
  menge numeric(8,2),
  primary key (lnr)
);
```

**tuples after joining the tables**

[image]

Now the task as mentioned is to get the manufacturers by name, who haven't had any sales in March 2002, which would be Pelikan, Geha and Brause. But after trying for way too long I can't seem to find anything that returns what I want.

Comment: I've gone ahead and removed the tag spam here; please only tag the RDBMS you are *really* using. Tagging multiple conflicting technologies makes your question unclear and thus *harder* to answer. It is also unlikely to get your question "more views" and likely to have the opposite effect, where only users who know *all* the RDBMS you have (mis)tagged will entertain the question; that is often a very small portion of the user base. Tag spam is far more likely to result in your question receiving downvotes and/or being closed as unclear. Please [edit] your question to retag the correct RDBMS.

Comment: don't know the Postgres code (or if it even works like this) but in SQL server I'd do something like SELECT columns FROM manufacturer WHERE hnr NOT IN (SELECT hnr INNER JOINS to product & delivery where month(datum) = 3)

Comment: @RickyTillson Had to change the syntax a little but it worked! Thanks 

Comment: Please don't link to images; add all relevant information directly to your question, preferably as editable text

Answer (score 0):

## Code

```
select manufacturer.name
from manufacturer
left join product
on manufacturer.hnr = product.hnr
left join delivery
on product.pnr = delivery.pnr and
   year(datum) = 12 and
   month(datum) = 3
where delivery.lnr is null;
```

## Explanation

We

- `select manufacturer.name`
- `from manufacturer`
- `left join`ing with `product` and `delivery` to make sure that even the `manufacturer` whose `product` and/or `delivery` does not meet the `join` criteria will have at least a record in the result, albeit, all nulls for `product` and/or `delivery` if there is no valid pair in those tables
- the `where` clause exludes any `manufacturers` who had a valid pair, that is, who meets the `join` criteria, where we included that the `product` was produced by the `manufacturer` and there was a `delivery` of the `product` in said period

## Why not subselecting

RickyTilson proposed something like

```
SELECT columns 
FROM manufacturer 
WHERE hnr NOT IN (
    SELECT hnr 
    INNER JOINS to product & delivery where month(datum) = 3
);
```

But I do not advise you to do this. In order to evaluate the `NOT IN` the RDBMS will have to list all product-delivery pair's hnr, which can become a huge list indeed, wasting resources both in time and memory. This is why, instead, I proposed an approach with `left join`.